# Python NoneType error in some executions of a program

Tags: python, nonetype

I was testing a code found in a book about Genetic Algorithms and I came up with an strange mistake. The code is the following:

```
import time
import random
import math

people = [('Seymour','BOS'),
          ('Franny','DAL'),
          ('Zooey','CAK'),
          ('Walt','MIA'),
          ('Buddy','ORD'),
          ('Les','OMA')]
# Laguardia
destination='LGA'

flights={}
# 
for line in file('schedule.txt'):
  origin,dest,depart,arrive,price=line.strip().split(',')
  flights.setdefault((origin,dest),[])

  # Add details to the list of possible flights
  flights[(origin,dest)].append((depart,arrive,int(price)))

def getminutes(t):
  x=time.strptime(t,'%H:%M')
  return x[3]*60+x[4]

def printschedule(r):
  for d in range(len(r)/2):
    name=people[d][0]
    origin=people[d][1]
    out=flights[(origin,destination)][int(r[d])]
    ret=flights[(destination,origin)][int(r[d+1])]
    print '%10s%10s %5s-%5s $%3s %5s-%5s $%3s' % (name,origin,
                                                  out[0],out[1],out[2],
                                                  ret[0],ret[1],ret[2])

def schedulecost(sol):
  totalprice=0
  latestarrival=0
  earliestdep=24*60

  for d in range(len(sol)/2):
    # Get the inbound and outbound flights
    origin=people[d][1]
    outbound=flights[(origin,destination)][int(sol[d])]
    returnf=flights[(destination,origin)][int(sol[d+1])]

    # Total price is the price of all outbound and return flights
    totalprice+=outbound[2]
    totalprice+=returnf[2]

    # Track the latest arrival and earliest departure
    if latestarrival<getminutes(outbound[1]): latestarrival=getminutes(outbound[1])
    if earliestdep>getminutes(returnf[0]): earliestdep=getminutes(returnf[0])

  # Every person must wait at the airport until the latest person arrives.
  # They also must arrive at the same time and wait for their flights.
  totalwait=0  
  for d in range(len(sol)/2):
    origin=people[d][1]
    outbound=flights[(origin,destination)][int(sol[d])]
    returnf=flights[(destination,origin)][int(sol[d+1])]
    totalwait+=latestarrival-getminutes(outbound[1])
    totalwait+=getminutes(returnf[0])-earliestdep  

  # Does this solution require an extra day of car rental? That'll be $50!
  if latestarrival>earliestdep: totalprice+=50

  return totalprice+totalwait


def geneticoptimize(domain,costf,popsize=50,step=1,
                    mutprob=0.2,elite=0.2,maxiter=100):
  # Mutation Operation
  def mutate(vec):
    i=random.randint(0,len(domain)-1)
    if random.random()<0.5 and vec[i]>domain[i][0]:
      return vec[0:i]+[vec[i]-step]+vec[i+1:] 
    elif vec[i]<domain[i][1]:
      return vec[0:i]+[vec[i]+step]+vec[i+1:]

  # Crossover Operation
  def crossover(r1,r2):
    i=random.randint(1,len(domain)-2)
    return r1[0:i]+r2[i:]

  # Build the initial population
  pop=[]
  for i in range(popsize):
    vec=[random.randint(domain[i][0],domain[i][1]) 
         for i in range(len(domain))]
    pop.append(vec)

  # How many winners from each generation?
  topelite=int(elite*popsize)

  # Main loop 
  for i in range(maxiter):
    scores=[(costf(v),v) for v in pop]
    scores.sort()
    ranked=[v for (s,v) in scores]

    # Start with the pure winners
    pop=ranked[0:topelite]

    # Add mutated and bred forms of the winners
    while len(pop)<popsize:
      if random.random()<mutprob:

        # Mutation
        c=random.randint(0,topelite)
        pop.append(mutate(ranked[c]))
      else:

        # Crossover
        c1=random.randint(0,topelite)
        c2=random.randint(0,topelite)
        pop.append(crossover(ranked[c1],ranked[c2]))

    # Print current best score
    print scores[0][0]

  return scores[0][1]
```

This code uses a .txt file called schedule.txt and that it can be downloaded from http://kiwitobes.com/optimize/schedule.txt

When I run the code I put the following, according to the book:

```
>>> domain=[(0,8)]*(len(optimization.people)*2)
>>> s=optimization.geneticoptimize(domain,optimization.schedulecost)
```

But the error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    s=optimization.geneticoptimize(domain,optimization.schedulecost)
  File "optimization.py", line 99, in geneticoptimize
    scores=[(costf(v),v) for v in pop]
  File "optimization.py", line 42, in schedulecost
    for d in range(len(sol)/2):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The thing is that the error message appears sometimes and other times not. I have checked the code and I cannot see where it can be the fault, because pop never is populated with empty vectors.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get `None` in your `pop` list if neither of the conditions in the `mutate` function are met. In that case the control runs off the end of the function, which is the same as returning `None`. You need to update the code to either have only one condition, or to handle a case that doesn't meet either of them in a separate block:

```
def mutate(vec):
    i=random.randint(0,len(domain)-1)
    if random.random()<0.5 and vec[i]>domain[i][0]:
        return vec[0:i]+[vec[i]-step]+vec[i+1:] 
    elif vec[i]<domain[i][1]:
        return vec[0:i]+[vec[i]+step]+vec[i+1:]
    else:
        # new code needed here!
```

Comment: I was just writing something similar.  The bug is actually in the book (Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications, Toby Segaran, pg. 98).

Comment: A proper code for the else clause would be to simply return `vec` unmodified. Also, for debugging code that uses PRNG be sure to set a seed.

Comment: Even if the code is updated to only check one condition, it will need an `else:` clause to avoid returning `None` when ever the condition not be satisfied (or perhaps `raise` an exception ti indicate something unexpected happened -- in which case an `assert` statement might be more appropriate).

Comment: @martineau: For a one condition solution, I was assuming the `elif` block would become the `else` case. I'm not sure if that would make sense for the algorithm, but it would at least not return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but I'd trap this error and print out the `pop` array when it arises to see what it looks like at the time.  It looks from the code like it should never get into this state, as you point out, so first look to see if it *does* get into that state, and then backtrack until you find the conditions where it happens.

Presumably this only happens sometimes because there are randomised factors in your code?